# Storing objects by superclass in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Is there some way I can store a collection of objects by a common superclass within a user class? My class structure is basically the following:

```
public abstract class Project { }

public class FooProject extends Project { }

public class BarProject extends Project { }

public class ApplicationUser {

    private Collection<Project> projects;

    public Collection<Project> getProjects() { ... }
    public void setProjects(...) { ... }

}

public interface ApplicationUserRepository extends MongoRepository<ApplicationUser, Long> { }
```

If I try to add a `FooProject`, e.g., to the `projects` collection and save the user, I start getting errors like `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: No property user found on entity class org.example.FooProject to bind constructor parameter to!`. I guess that's because there's no setter in the `ApplicationUser` class to handle `FooProject`.

I've seen some questions / examples where subclasses are given the same `@Collection` annotation, but I'm not sure what that really buys me. And in those examples, a separate repository interface was declared for each type. And even then, how would I associate a reference to a `FooProject` from a different repository with a user? Ideally, I'd have just one repository for `ApplicationUser` objects, or maybe two, for `ApplicationUser` and superclass `Project`. Each project will only ever be associated with one user.